# Using xrandr freezes computer completely

Tags: xorg, multi-monitor, xrandr, freeze

I have the following problem: I have a laptop (open) with an external monitor connected. After boot, everything is perfect - the laptop screen is on the left of the external one and both resolutions are max and so on.

However, If I use xrandr to, for example, turn off the laptop screen

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --off
```

The system freezes completely - both screens turn black and I can only see a mouse pointer on the external screen (it doesn't move). All keyboard shortcuts to kill X and so on don't work, and I have to hard reset the laptop.

I can't find anything in the log files neither of Xorg nor in the system messages.

Here is some output that might be helpful:

```
$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3286 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1366x768       60.0*+   40.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI3 connected 1920x1080+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I have an Intel arrandale chip, the i915 kernel module is loaded as well as KMS. Turning off modesetting at boot totally screws up my resolution and so on.

I googled a little bit and found that freezes using xrandr are known, but I didn't find any solution yet.

Comment: It's a bug, and your best bet is to contact the authors of your video driver (see if they have a mailing list) and ask them how you can help (e.g. by running the driver in a debugging mode and collecting crash information).

Comment: It's definitely a video driver bug, I agree.  I've seen many-a-laptop with similar issues.  Many times drivers work the first time, but not later times, etc.

Comment: Any updates? Was the bug fixed in new versions?

Comment: I have the same problem with nVidia GT420. Please let me know if you were able to solve the issue.

Comment: Maybe some type of an unwaited/unneeded interaction between the X.org and the fb drivers?